# Creating an hourly sum (Mysql)

Tags: mysql

I am a PHP/MySQL novice and don't really know how to solve this.

table Users has columns id, name, totals

table Images has columns userid, views, newviews

views is a constantly growing number. newviews is also growing with views but I want to reset it every X hours and add the value of newviews to totals. So every X hours the newviews is 0 and the views keeps the old value.

How can I do this?

bare in mind that the are multiple Images and multiple Users and Images newviews need to be added to the totals of the Image owner...

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MySQL Events`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html),

From the documentation,

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

Note that the `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` is the directive which is important here. Also from the docs

> This statement creates and schedules a new event. The event will not run unless the Event Scheduler is enabled.